# Overlapping divs for custom vertical scrollbar fails

Tags: css

I have a custom vertical scrollbar.
It has the next structure:

```
div (general container)-- style table height 300 px

   div "uparrow"    style tablerow height 20px

   div "slider"     style tablerow NO height (automATIC)

      div "line or guide" 

      div "for handle"

   div "downarrow"  style tablerow height 20px
```

Ok, this works fine. 
I can change the general container height and every is resized rightly.

My problem: I want to place the vertical handle absolutely inside the 'slider'.
(I have javascript code to set the style.top )

I want 'center' for both the line & the handle.
Using margin-left: auto margin-right:auto works fine for the 'line' but then the slider is not placed good.

I'm playing with some relative / absolute combinations without success.

Also I'm playing placing the handle inside the line, also with wrong results.

The image shows what I want (in this case uparrow & downarrow are empty)

Any ideas and advise?

[image: scrollbar]

Comment: Please provide a fiddle for us or actual code.

Comment: @Mouser I have no code (I have 6 div & 6 styles). I simply want to overlap two divs inside another and then place them automatically center horizontall the first & abs. place vertically the second

Comment: You are talking about setting the style.top with javascript and playing with position in css. So you have css, html and JavaScript. It's easier to help if we could see that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent div should have `position: relative`. The slider button `position: absolute` and `left: 50%` the `margin-left` should be the minus half of its width. Example if the width is `20px` the margin left should be `-10px`.

The position absolute allows to flow the button over the slider. Position relative forces the slider to obey the offset of the parent div. Left 50% places the left border of the element in the center. The actually centering gets done by the margin-left. It sets the element back with the half of its width.

With pure css example:

```
    div.sliderContainer {
        width: 30px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
        border: 2px solid #99B2FF;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
        padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    }

    div.sliderLine {
        width: 4px;
        outline: 1px solid #888888;
        background-color: #AAAAAA;
        box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
        margin: auto auto;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 100%;
    }

    div.sliderButton {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 20px;
        margin-left: -10px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 20px;
        height: 30px;
        border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
        box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px #ffffff;          
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="slider_01" class="sliderContainer">
    <div class="sliderLine"></div>
    <div class="sliderButton"></div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7sLjjyj/) as proof.

Comment: thanks. ... I'd not want to deal with adds and subs with the widths and so on. But I think it is impossible to find an automatic behaviour...

Comment: @civiltomain have a look a the update code or fiddle.